# Is it "kelly pool" or "Kelly pool"?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Kelly pool is a "cue sport" played on a pool table like billiards, snooker, and other variants of pool.

But which is more accepted? Capitalised or not? Or are both OK?

Comment: a google search indicates that most sources capitalize Kelly and some capitalize Pool.

Comment: The Wikipedia article uses lowercase but it may be named after a person or at least be perceived to be. I don't have access to a nice fat descriptive OED or Websters here though (-:

Comment: It appears that it is named after a person. In that case, since there is some ambiguity, I would capitalize it.

Comment: Apparently the person it's named after wasn't named Kelly though - but at that point I stopped reading further (-:

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick Google search, convention seems to dictate that "kelly pool" be spelt without a capital K. This is interesting as, according to Wikipedia, kelly pool was indeed named after the inventor (his nickname was Kelly).